# babel-preset-stage-0 without transform-async-generator-functions

Tags: node.js, async-await, babeljs

I want to use `babel-preset-stage-0`, but I'm using Node.js `>= v7.6`, so I don't need `transform-async-generator-functions` anymore.

Is there an elegant way to do that?

Comment: You'd be much better off enabling the specific experimental plugins that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a preset [babel-preset-stage-0-without-async](https://github.com/Cap32/babel-preset-stage-x-without-async/tree/master/babel-preset-stage-0-without-async) by using [modify-babel-preset](https://github.com/developit/modify-babel-preset)